# why does Pthread Signal from main, hangs the code?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

The requirement for the sample application creating using pthread is given below:

1. A single thread is created from main using Pthread
2. Inside thread, Mutex is locked, a counter counts the value and while loop is incremented, While is set to the max count of 10.
3. after while loop finishes, the mutex is unlocked.

The above requirement I have tried implementing using pthread

Code is shown below:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
pthread_mutex_t count_mutex;
pthread_cond_t count_threshold_cv;

int samples = 10;
int count = 0;

struct example
{
    int i;
    int a;
};

void *inc_x(void *x_void_ptr)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
    printf("Thread is locked \n");

    while(count < samples)
    {
    printf("inside While loop \n");

    struct example *E2_ptr;
    E2_ptr = (struct example *)x_void_ptr;
    printf("inside thread count = %d\n",count);
    E2_ptr->a = count;
    E2_ptr->i = (count + 1);
    count ++;
    //pthread_cond_wait(&count_threshold_cv, &count_mutex);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
    printf ( "\n Test Successful for Thread\n");

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{

    int x = 100, y = 0,i = 0;
    struct example *E1_ptr;

    E1_ptr->a = 0;
    E1_ptr->i = 0;

    printf("Before\t E1_ptr->a = %d\t, E1_ptr->i = %d\n",E1_ptr->a,E1_ptr->i);


    pthread_t inc_x_thread;


    if(pthread_create(&inc_x_thread, NULL, inc_x, E1_ptr))
    {
    printf("Error creating thread\n");
    }


    if(pthread_join(inc_x_thread, NULL))
    {
    printf("Error joining thread\n");
    }

    for(i  = 0; i<(samples-1); i++)
    {
    if(pthread_cond_signal(&count_threshold_cv))
    {
         printf("Error Signaling thread at sample = %d\n",i);
    }
    }


    printf("after\t E1_ptr->a = %d\t, E1_ptr->i = %d\n",E1_ptr->a,E1_ptr->i);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&count_mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&count_threshold_cv);
    pthread_exit (NULL);


    return 0;
}
```

Doubt:

In the above code, the thread executes its function properly and exits.
Once the condition is applied, i.e. the below shown code is uncommented then,

```
pthread_cond_wait(&count_threshold_cv, &count_mutex);
```

Then the thread is stopped after 1st iteration of while loop as expected.
The signal is generated from main by the code shown below:

```
for(i  = 0; i<(samples-1); i++)
{
    if(pthread_cond_signal(&count_threshold_cv))
    {
         printf("Error Signaling thread at sample = %d\n",i);
    }
}
```

observed that the signal is never sent.

Can someone please guide me, where am I going wrong. I'm a newbie to Pthreads.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is because you join before you signal. Join will wait till thread finishes. Thread will wait till you signal. this is a dead lock. Move join closer to the end of the program.

Comment: thanks for suggestion serge, but after that also program had same behavior. It hangs after 1st iteration. Does signaling of thread is normal from main.

Answer (score 0):

`count_mutex` and `count_threshold_cv` are not initialized, add:

```
int main()
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&count_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&count_threshold_cv, NULL);
    //...
```

---

`E1_ptr` is not initialized.
There are many ways to solve it:

You can call `malloc` to allocate memory:

```
struct example *E1_ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct example));

E1_ptr->a = 0;
E1_ptr->i = 0;
```

or holds pointer to local variable:

```
struct example ex;
struct example *E1_ptr = &ex; //malloc(sizeof(struct example));

E1_ptr->a = 0;
E1_ptr->i = 0;
```

or

```
struct example ex;
ex.a = 0;
ex.i = 0;
```

then create thread with `pthread_create(&inc_x_thread, NULL, inc_x, &ex)`

---

`pthread_cond_signal` function does not wait. If a thread is blocked by condition variable `pthread_cond_signal` function unblocks this thread, otherwise returns immediately without waiting and does nothing. So your for loop with 10 iterations is executed as soon as possible, without any waiting for `pthread_cond_wait` is called.
So can rewrite your for loop to infinite loop, calling `pthread_cond_signal` repeatedly.

```
if(pthread_create(&inc_x_thread, NULL, inc_x, E1_ptr)) {
   printf("Error creating thread\n");
} 

while(1) { // INFINITE LOOP
    if(pthread_cond_signal(&count_threshold_cv)) {
         printf("Error Signaling thread at sample = %d\n",i);
    }

    if (taskDone) // testing global flag, if 1 break
        break; // it means inc_x thread has ended
}

if(pthread_join(inc_x_thread, NULL)) { // it was pointed out in comment
printf("Error joining thread\n"); // you need to join at the end of main function
}
```

`taskDone` is global *int*, with 0 as default value. It is set to `1` before `pthread_exit` is called in `inc_x` function. Setting/checking `taskDone` should be wrapped with some synchronization mechanism, for example by adding new mutex or use `count_mutex`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. 
i was assuming that in each iteration of for loop i shall be calling the thread and finish its execution till another iteration of for loop is performed.
was trying to achieve something like that

Comment: is there a way that same thread can be called again and again?
or at each iteration of for loop i shall create a new thread?

Comment: if a thread was started you have 2 options: joins this thread or detaches it. You cannot call *again* the same thread, you need to create new one.